# Can we get frreeSWITCH outbound call duration from an API

Tags: freeswitch

I am trying to find an API or a method that can get the call duration from FreeSWITCH. As my search, we can get call duration from `fs_cdr` table or calculate the time between `CHANNEL_HANGUP` - `CHANNEL_ANSWER` events.

Currently, we are having a problem with the call duration, the time did not match when comparing the value in fs_cdr table and events time. So I am trying to find out if FreeSWITCH provides an API so that we can get the accurate duration or not. I am new to FS so if you can suggest me a way to find it, it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Use *mod_json_cdr* module they send data in json after hangup call and in *billsec* variable you can get call duration in seconds.